# windows script to run after a specific time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am wondering if there is any command for windows script that makes the execution of the script halt for some time before continuing executing it?

e.g: run the first two commands in a script, wait 10 seconds then continue executing

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the waitfor command. Check out the documentation [here](http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html).

Answer (score 7):

I guess you are looking for `timeout` command.

```
@echo off

command1
REM wait for 10 seconds before executing command2
timeout /t 10
command2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To prevent an accidental key press which will start your following script earlier, could use `timeout /t 10 /nobreak`. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/timeout)